# Java: change a variable depending on dynamically generated text field name?

Tags: java, swing, variables, dynamic, jtextfield

I have an ArrayList of TrainingClass objects with a variable "priority".

I am making a settings frame, where for each element currently in the ArrayList I make a TextField where the user sets priority.

This is how it is generated

```
for (TrainingClass tclass : mTrainingClasses) {
                  //Loop the ArrayList
        JTextField txtPriority = new JTextField(3);
        txtPriority.setBounds(10,10,100,20);
        txtPriority.setText("" + tclass.getPriority());
        getContentPane().add(txtPriority);
 }
```

Now I would add a change listener, but...

Once I know which field has been changed, how can I access the proper element of the ArrayList mTrainingClasses?

In php, for example, I would simply make something like:

```
 $mTrainingClasses->$changed_field->setPriority($new_value);
```

But, as far as I understand, I can’t do this in Java. So, how should I proceed?

Do I need to manually set the field name and listener for each element? I’m sure there is some other solution, but I have no idea at this point.

(I know I could use an ArrayList for the fields as well, such as

```
txtPriority.add(new JTextField(3));
```

But in this case, how do I know which index corresponds to the field that has been changed?
)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a list of Text Fields

```
List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
```

Change the loop like the following where you add all text fields to above list

```
for (TrainingClass tclass : mTrainingClasses) {
        //Loop the ArrayList
        JTextField txtPriority = new JTextField(3);
        txtPriority.setBounds(10,10,100,20);
        txtPriority.setText("" + tclass.getPriority());
        getContentPane().add(txtPriority);
        textFields.add(txtPriority);
}
```

In your listener you can do the following

```
mTrainingClasses.get(textFields.indexOf((JtextField) event.getSource()));
```

The above will return the TrainingClass which got changed.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options:

- Pass the `TrainingClass` element to the listener which you attach to the textfield. This will require to attach the listener in your `for` loop where you have access to both the `TrainingClass` and `JTextField` variable
- Use a `Map` as suggested by @Ted Hopp
- Use a `List` as you already suggested. Trick is to store an index in the `JTextField` so that afterwards you know which `JTextField` corresponds to which element in the `List`. You can use `JComponent#putClientProperty` and `JComponent#getClientProperty` for this.
- You can use those `JComponent#putClientProperty` and `JComponent#getClientProperty` methods to store the `TrainingClass` variable directly

Answer (score 3):

In your loop, you can populate a `Map<JTextField, TrainingClass>`. Then you can use that to look up the element from the changed field.

```
Map<JTextField, TrainingClass> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
for (TrainingClass tclass : mTrainingClasses) {
    //Loop the ArrayList
    JTextField txtPriority = new JTextField(3);
    txtPriority.setBounds(10,10,100,20);
    txtPriority.setText("" + tclass.getPriority());
    getContentPane().add(txtPriority);
    map.put(txtPriority, tclass);
}
```

Alternatively, you can subclass JTextField and declare a data field that you can then reference directly in event handling.

Answer (score 3):

You need some kind of mapping between the JTextField and the TrainingClass. Either make text field a property of your class or make a map that maps the two.

```
Map<TrainingClass, JTextField> myMap= new HashMap<TrainingClass, JTextField>();

for (TrainingClass tclass : mTrainingClasses) {
              //Loop the ArrayList
    JTextField txtPriority = new JTextField(3);
    txtPriority.setBounds(10,10,100,20);
    txtPriority.setText("" + tclass.getPriority());
    getContentPane().add(txtPriority);

    // map the textField to the training class
    myMap.put(txtPriority, tclass);
}
```

When the field changes inside the listener method, you'd simply call:

```
public void eventListenerMethod(InputEvent e) {
     JTextField fieldThatGeneratedEvent= e.getSource();
     TrainingClass tClass= myMap.get(fieldThatGeneratedEvent);
}
```